# Duplicate entry '19' for key 'PRIMARY' insert php mysql

Tags: php, mysqli, insert, duplicates, primary-key

I am quite new to PHP.
At the moment I am trying to insert a new row to a table in the mysql-database via PHP.

In there there are only 7 entries so far with ids 1-7.
No matter what (higher) number I use for the ID-column, though, I always get back "Duplicate entry '19' for key 'PRIMARY'" from the browser:

> Error: INSERT INTO tbl_Fotografen (FotografenID, FotografAnrede, FotografVorname, FotografNachname, Fotostudio, FotografStraße, FotografPLZOrt, FotografBundesland, FotografBereich, FotografFestnetz, FotografMobil, FotografEMail, FotografWebsite, Honorar, KmPauschale, FotografIBAN, Besonderheiten, aktiv) VALUES (19, 'Herr', 'Konrad', 'König', 'keins', '', '', 'Bayern', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1');
>   
> Duplicate entry '19' for key 'PRIMARY'

The PRIMARY KEY in this case is the first column (FotografenID).

When I am copying the statement and (after deleting the just created row) entering the exact same in phpmyadmin directly, I don't get this error message though.

What can be wrong? 
(The PRIMARY KEY IS INT UNSIGNED, NOT NULL, AUTO-INCREMENT)
What I also don't understand is, why it does the entry nevertheless although it "thinks" that there already is an entry with this primary key.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could it be that, for some reason, the query is executed twice?

Comment: If it's auto-increment, why are you specifying it explicitly instead of letting it fill in automatically?

Comment: Dear rickdenhaan, I thought about that, too. For testing that I put an if-statement in the code in case of successful inserting the data which should then show in the browser before the error. But no success message is showing although the data is in the database.

Comment: Dear Barmar, it doesn't accept an empty column eather. Then it says You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 'Herr', 'Konrad', 'König', 'keins', '', '', 'Bayern', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' at line 1. Additionally I sometimes need to be able to insert old data where there are e.g. IDs missing but still the old IDs need to be kept and in mysql itself I never had problems with that as long as the IDs were "free".

Comment: What happens if you put `NULL` instead of `19` for the `FotografenID` value?

Comment: That works and helped me to find the right solution! I still got two entries in my database but could now find that I executed the statement again in the if-statement that I used to inform me of correct execution... What should I say... ;-) After fixing that it works as should. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
The answer shows up in my last comment. (Code was executed twice because of additional if-statement).